# How to display currency in opensearch dashboard?

Tags: kibana, opensearch

How to display the US Dollar sign ($) in Opensearch Dashboard field? I couldn't find any documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I finally found the answer!

1. Go to Management --> Stack Management

[image]

2. Then Index Patterns -->

[image]

3. There will be a pencil icon on the field where you need to make the change.

[image]

4. Add the following fields and save.

[image]